# MITM Attacks over SSL

Tags: tls, attack-prevention, man-in-the-middle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How might the U.K. Government's proposed internet surveillance equipment “bypass” encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16971/how-might-the-u-k-governments-proposed-internet-surveillance-equipment-bypass)

If I have a server (call it server 1) set up to receive POST data from another server (server 2) over SSL, and then server 1 does stuff with the POST data, what is there to stop a MITM intercepting the entire SSL payload and then sending it off to server 1 at a later time?

I realise that the MITM won't be able to see or modify the data, but couldn't they keep on sending it to server 1 and cause it to do something that we don't really want?

Comment: Have you searched previous questions with [MITM and SSL tags](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mitm+ssl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL does not guarantee that MiTM will not occur. A proxy server can intercept SSL. There are corporate solutions to intercept SSL for logging purposes.

You are talking about a replay attack. Possibly, but redundant packets with the same data should be dropped. If you do not have the unencrypted body to manipulate a replay attack would be only as useful as just any DoS attack.

Some Links

- http://crypto.stanford.edu/ssl-mitm/
- http://mitmproxy.org/
- http://stason.org/TULARC/security/ssl-talk/4-1-Does-SSL-protect-users-from-replay-attack-by-eavesdropp.html

Related Questions
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769992/replay-attacks-for-https-requests
 -http://serverfault.com/questions/32473/does-https-include-protection-from-a-replay-attack